# How to set base ip address for all new docker networks

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

When I create a new network, docker creates it with an address like 172.255.255.255 (172.17.1.0, 172.18.1.0, etc). But this could conflict with external addresses, since all machines in my network has the same prefix (172.255.255.255)

Is there a way to configure a base subnet address to be used by docker at creation of new networks?

[Update] I'm creating and deleting networks automatically, so, I can't set the --subnet option (since I don't know what address are in use or not). I need that docker manages the pool of address dynamically, like it manages the ingress network (auto allocating and prune subnets). Actually, what I need is only customize the ingress base address!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default network is named bridge. That is setup  to use the 172 range.

What you need to do is create your own bridge network.

```
$ docker network create -d bridge my_bridge
(use the --ip-range option)
```

Then you can add a container to that network.

```
$ docker run -d --net=my_bridge --name db training/postgres
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/networkingcontainers/

Comment: Unfortunately it will not work for me... (I updated my question!)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I updated the answer to address the additional details you provided in the question.

Answer (score 5):

[Docker 18.06 introduces the `--default-address-pool` option](https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-ce/#18060-ce-2018-07-18). With it you can specify the address range that user defined networks will use by default instead of the standard `172.x`
You can see the pull requests where the features has been implemented and discussed for more information: [moby/29376](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/29376), [moby/36054](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/36054), [moby/36396](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/36396),

You can set the parameter as a command line argument to the docker daemon:

> #### `--default-addr-pool`
>
> This flag specifies default subnet pools for global scope networks.
>   Format example is `--default-addr-pool 30.30.0.0/16 --default-addr-pool 40.40.0.0/16`

Or in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
  "default-address-pools": [
    {"base":"172.80.0.0/16","size":24}
  ]
}
```

Comment: The right syntax for cli argument is `--default-addr-pool name=30.30.0.0,size=16`